# How did Staudinger demonstrate that polymers are high molecular weight covalently bonded molecules?

Tags: chemistry

[Hermann Staudinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Staudinger) was awarded the 1953 Nobel Prize in Chemistry for his work demonstrating that [polymers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer) are high molecular weight covalently bonded molecules. Prior to his work, the consensus among chemists was that polymers were loosely aggregated of smaller molecules, similar to what today we call a [colloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid).

Unfortunately for me, Staudinger published in German, and my German reading skills are not quite good enough to understand his papers. What I would like to know is: what evidence did Staudinger use to convince his contemporaries that polymers are high molecular weight molecules?